# MongoError: can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 2dsphere (needs index) $nearSphere

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geospatial, mongodb-query

This is my first question here so please be patient with me if its not asked very well or if my english is bad.

I am trying do Geospatioal Querys in MongoDB in Node.js.

This query works just fine

```
collection.find( { loc : { $geoWithin :
    { $centerSphere :
        [ [ point.coordinates[0], point.coordinates[1]] , getRadiusMeters(radius) ]
    } } } )
```

but when i try to do the same with $nearSphere:

```
collection.find(  { loc :{ $nearSphere :
            { $geometry :
            { type : "Point" ,
                coordinates : [ point.coordinates[0], point.coordinates[1]] } ,
                $maxDistance : getRadiusMeters(radius)
            } } } )
```

I get the following Error:

```
{ [MongoError: can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 2dsphere (needs index),  for: { loc: { $nearSphere: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 6.128777, 49.596792 ] }, $maxDistance: 10000 } } }] name: 'MongoError' }
```

I think i have the right indexes. Here are my Indexes:

```
> db.realtrip.getIndexes()
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "test.realtrip",
            "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "loc" : "2dsphere"
            },
            "ns" : "test.realtrip",
            "name" : "loc_2dsphere"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "tags" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "test.realtrip",
            "name" : "tags_1"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "loc" : "2d"
            },
            "ns" : "test.realtrip",
            "name" : "loc_2d"
    }
]
```

I cant find what I am doing wrong. The $centerSphere Query works just fine only the $nearSphere Query gives me Errors.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run the following command? ```collection.ensureIndex({loc: '2dsphere'}, function(err, result) { console.log(err); collection.geoNear(point.coordinates[0], point.coordinates[1], {spherical: true, maxDistance: getRadiusMeters(radius)}, function(err, docs) { console.log(err); }); });```

Comment: i got: 
null
null
plus the following in my mongodb window:
build index realtrip.geo_data { loc: "2dsphere" }
build index done.  scanned 12932 total records. 0.454 secs
insert realtrip.system.indexes ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:489707 489ms

Comment: And what's the value of `docs`? Do you get any documents from MongoDB?

Comment: It looks like that solves the problem with the Indexes. collection.geoNear gives me a array with distances. My original query now returns an empty array but im confident that i can get it to work now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turned out my bug was related to this issue [Bugreport Mongodb](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4572)

Updating my mongodb solved it. Now the code works as expected.